# Differenze tra "testimone", "testimonio" e "testimonianza"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, vocabulary, nouns

Questi tre vocaboli, "testimone", "testimonio" e "testimonianza", mi sembrano molto simili. Non capisco bene quali sono le differenze di uso e di significato tra loro. Me le potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il testimone o la testimone è la persona che testimonia. Per estensione, anche una cosa che svolge lo stesso ruolo può essere chiamata *testimone* (Come in *L'unica testimone del delitto è stata la videocamera di sorveglianza*). http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimone/

La testimonianza è ciò che afferma il testimone, è il ruolo svolto dal testimone. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimonianza/

La parola *testimonio* (ormai poco utilizzata, ma da cui derivano entrambe le altre) può indicare sia il testimone sia la testimonianza. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/testimonio/

Comment: Tutto giusto, e faccio notare (come peraltro dicono anche le voci Treccani) che in ambito giudiziario si usa molto anche “teste” per “testimone”.

Comment: Perché "testimonio" è poco utilizzata? È l'indicativo di *testimoniare*...

Comment: Hai ragione: come verbo, _testimonio_ non è una parola insolita. Come sostantivo, sì. La domanda per come l'ho intesa io riguardava le tre parole usate come sostantivi.